# Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

About 2 weeks ago some SQL that has been working for the past 6 months started throwing an error without anything changing. I spent a couple days trying to find out what was going on and it just did not make any sense.

Eventually, I tried just an "alter" on the Stored Procedure (which had no effect) and then eventually dropped and recreated it (which did fix it).

Then, 2 days ago, the error came back and this time even the drop/create is not fixing it. According to my IT guys, they have not patched the SQL Servers in 1.5 months so there was nothing changed there. Does anyone have any ideas or has had the same issues?

This line of code, in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT LabelText + Data
FROM CU_FormLayout fl
    INNER JOIN CU_Data dat ON dat.LayoutId = fl.Id
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT RIGHT(fl.xLabelText,1) RightChar) ca2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(RightChar) BETWEEN 49 AND 57 OR 
                                ASCII(RightChar) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 OR 
                                ASCII(RightChar) BETWEEN 97 AND 122
                            THEN fl.xLabelText + ': '
                            ELSE fl.xLabelText + ' ' END LabelText) ca1
```

Causes this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

As you can see, the only `RIGHT()` has a hard-coded length. How could it be invalid?

BTW, the point of this code is that it takes a "Label" from one column and if it ends with a letter or number, add ": " and then the data value the label is for. Other-wise just put a space between them.

Comment: Do you have by any chance the exact data (`fl.xLabelText`) for which the error is thrown?

Comment: @TT. The above SQL runs it for the entire table, and it does NOT error. The SQL in the SP includes a `WHERE` clause that does this for a single ID. It does not matter which one I do it on, it errors every time in the SP. The end result is this is stuffed into a variable that is then used for an email to a user. I cannot reproduce the error, except through the full SP. Even if I copy all the code and put it in a script, it runs fine. As I mentioned, the last time I fixed it, it was through a DROP/CREATE. No code change at all.

Comment: Perhaps if you can't find the cause (it's probably bugging production environment), you could rewrite using `SUBSTRING`? Or a combination of `REVERSE` & `LEFT`?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the "IT guys" to check if there's any outstanding SP's for SQL Server 2012 they haven't installed?

Comment: @TT. I switched to the `REVERSE` and `LEFT` just so I could see something change and I get the same error (regarding the `RIGHT`). So I obviously am missing a trigger or something somewhere that is the issue, not my SP. I will post more in a few.

Comment: @TT. Found it (down the rabbit hole). It was exactly what the error says it was just not where I was looking. Your suggestion resulted in me finding it so if you make it the answer, I will mark it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you can't find the cause (it's probably bugging production environment), you could rewrite using `SUBSTRING`? Or a combination of `REVERSE` & `LEFT`.

Comment: By doing this I was able to find that my issue was somewhere else because my code gave the same error, when it shouldn't have. Thanks